# How to print Arrays that are inputed by user (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have no idea how to put this...

basically, We are supposed to make an Array. where we input the number of students, their names, and age. after that an output will be displayed. It will show the names and age of a student.

It seems easy for you to look at. but I really need advice on how to shorten the output. like if there is anything I could do to minimize the code and make an infinite number of outputs so that I can input any number of students.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int ageInput;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Number of Students > ");
                int studentValue = input.nextInt();
            String[] arraylist = new String[studentValue];
            int[] ageinput = new int[studentValue];

            char count;
                for (count = 0; count < studentValue; count++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please input a student name and age:");
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Name: ");
                    arraylist[count] = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Age: ");
                    ageinput[count] = input2.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }

                for (String a: arraylist)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Student #1");
                        System.out.println("name: " +arraylist[0]);
                        System.out.println("age: " +ageinput[0]);

                        System.out.println("Student #2");
                        System.out.println("name: " +arraylist[1]);
                        System.out.println("age: " +ageinput[1]);

                        System.out.println("Student #3");
                        System.out.println("name: " +arraylist[2]);
                        System.out.println("age: " +ageinput[2]);

                        System.out.println("Student #4");
                        System.out.println("name: " +arraylist[3]);
                        System.out.println("age: " +ageinput[3]);

                        System.out.println("Student #5");
                        System.out.println("name: " +arraylist[4]);
                        System.out.println("age: " +ageinput[4]);
                    }

    }
```

}

I'm not very good at this stuff. soo if you could answer the question I really appreciate it :) Thank you all!

Comment: Please concentrate on the question. Thinking about your or our skills does not help, and I suggest you remove those parts from your question.

Comment: 1. create a separate class which holds name and age. 2. create an array of that class (Student [] students = new Student[studentValue]). 3. create a `new Student(name, age)` for every entry and add to array. 4. overwrite `toString()` method in student class 5. use for loop to iterare over the array and use `System.out.println(student.toString())` if done correctly, it will solve your problem

Comment: @C-Otto sure, thank you for suggesting. I'm just soo insecure in these kinds of situations.

Comment: Creating two `Scanner`s on the same stream sounds weird to me

Comment: You can also use Arrays.toString() to print the array.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I will try this out thank you!

Comment: @MauricePerry well, yeahh i didn't think of removing that, no idea why.

Comment: `for (String a: arraylist)` is not the type of loop you need here

Comment: @RioAblas we all started somewhere. Don't be afraid to just ask straight-forward questions on StackOverflow, and feel free to leave out formalities. There really is no need to explain WHY you are asking a question, as long as you provide all the information we need to help.

Comment: @C-Otto *noted* thank you for the advice good sir!!

Comment: @cricket_007 yeahh figured, I just thought it would help(?) while I was stressing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a loop to print your results i suggest you are using the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <studentValue; i++)
{
   System.out.println("Student #" + i + 1);
   System.out.println("name: " + arraylist[i]);
   System.out.println("age: " + ageinput[i]);
}
```